# Can a Greens Lemon Meringue Pie be frozen?

Tags: pie, meringue

Can you freeze the completely made cold lemon meringue pie, and will it look and taste the same after freezing, or will it freeze better without the meringue? Alternatively, can it be made a day in advance and stored in the fridge successfully overnight.

Comment: what is special about a "greens" Lemon Meringue Pie? Is that a brand? A recipe?

Comment: I suspect that it's a typo, but I can't figure out for what.

Answer (score 1):

I assume here we are talking about this type of LMP:

[image]

If so, I would recommend storing it in the fridge overnight, although it will probably loose some crispness being in a moist environment. Ideally, I would try and make it on the day for best results.